# $3$-dimensional convex hull using only a desired number of planes

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I would like to find the convex polytope with the smallest volume that envelops (contains) all the points of a given 3D point cloud and that can be constructed from *only* $k$ planes. This is similar to the convex hull problem, except that the convex hull can have an arbitrary large number of faces (limited only by $n$, the size of the input) while I am looking for a polytope with only $k$ faces (say, $k=8$).

Another way to phrase the problem:

> Given a large 3D point cloud with $n$ points and a small number $k$, find $k$ planes so that all points are in the polytope created by the union of the planes and that polytope has the smallest possible volume.

All "exact" convex hull algorithms I looked at (*Gift wrapping*, *Graham scan*, *Quickhull*) produce a polytope with a lot of faces and I can't see a way of reducing the number of faces after computing the convex hull (by merging adjacent faces or so until the face count is down to k or less).
From the "approximative" convex hull algorithms, I have thought of computing the discrete orientation polytope (k-DOP, see [this PPT](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwjOrdPO1sHPAhUHJR4KHT8WDtUQFghXMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.qub.ac.uk%2F~P.Hanna%2FCSC3049%2Fresources%2F2.3.%2520Bounding%2520volumes.pptx&usg=AFQjCNGAPJ_MrSGbgQIXSquTVi2nbIvWWQ&sig2=tr4c-tvfeE0malc-sJ0SkA&cad=rja)), but that would not be optimal (the volume would not be minimal) because it requires that each face has a parallel "partner face".

I would be happy to hear your thoughts on how to do this!

Comment: Take a look at "Minimum area circumscribing Polygons" by Alok Aggarwal, J.S. Chang and Chee K. Yap, and see if you can generalize to three dimensions.